# How do I make the Pro version of my app replace or get rid of the free version?

Tags: android

How do I make the Pro version of my app replace or get rid of the free version? after the user has downloaded and installed the Pro version... since I'm sure they wouldn't want both apps on the phone.

Comment: Sort of OT, but is your free app out there yet? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make the Pro version of my app replace or get rid of the free version?

You don't.

> after the user has downloaded and installed the Pro version... since I'm sure they wouldn't want both apps on the phone.

The user can uninstall the free version if and when the user wishes, using the standard ways built into Android (e.g., tap-and-hold the launcher icon and drag it over "Uninstall" on Android 3.0+).

After all, the Pro version may be buggy, or lack the ability to import data from the free version, or otherwise suffer from problems that may cause the user to return to the free version. Or, they may uninstall the Pro version during the brief return period, believing that it is not worth the money.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, strictly speaking. You may have some luck with [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) to enable pro features in your free app, though.